# Get website regex from a website link

Tags: regex

if I have a website like: www.google.com/en/my-page/anotherpage

how is it possible that with reg-ex to get: /en/my-page ? I am using this reg-ex in the IIS?

So far I have done something similar to this:

```
    ^(?:\\.|[^/\\])*/((?:\\.|[^/\\])*)/
```

but it is returning /en/my-page/ and I want it to return /en/my-page

Comment: You don't need regex. `part = substring(url, strpos('/', url));` This is pseudo-code of course, since there is not specified language.

Comment: Or, you can parse the URL using a URL parser and take the path and everything after.

Comment: Try this:    ^(?:\\.|[^/\\])*(/[^/\\]+)*

Comment: What's the language used here?

Comment: i am using URL rewrite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one should suit your needs:

```
^[^/]+(/.*)/[^/]+$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Visualization by [Debuggex](http://www.debuggex.com/r/It97W_fTiyteNRuE).

The output your looking for is in the first captured group.

Demo on [RegExr](http://regexr.com?367u5).

Comment: thank you very much this explained me a lot how it should be done :)

Answer (score 1):

In grep your regex is returning the string "www.google.com/en/". You can simply use the following regex if positive look behind is not mandatory :

```
(/[^/]+)+
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a look-ahead assertion to get rid of the last slash:

```
/\/.*(?=\/)/
```